# Slim 3 direct access to a file

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I want to make a route to directly access to a document.
For example, I want to access to `domain/file/document.pdf` but by `domain/doc`.

I tried this:

```
$app->get('/docs/v1', function ($request, $response){
    $this->view->render( $response, '/docs/document.pdf');
});
```

But it doesn't work. I also saw this on the official doc:

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
$app->get('/hello', function ($req, $res) {
    $this['view']->display('profile.html', [
        'name' => 'Josh',
        'url' => 'https://joshlockhart.com'
    ]);
});
```

But the display function does not exist.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Slim\Views\PhpRenderer::display()
```

Maybe I missed something, I don't know, I didn't find anything else in the doc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points here:

1) In Slim v3, "$this['view']" typically points to your Twig renderer. So you're trying to call a Twig renderer, which is probably not what you want to do in this case.

2) The correct syntax to invoke a Twig renderer and return it's output is

```
return $this->view->render ($response, 'yourTemplate.twig', [ ... array of parameters goes here ...]);
```

3) As for directly accessing a document (I've never done this before, so my answer might be wrong), you probably want to redirect to the document itself like this:

```
return $response->withRedirect ((string)($request->getUri()->withPath('path/to/document')));
```

and just let the browser deal with how to handle that document type.

Hope this helps.